# Converting CASE WHEN into IIF

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I mainly work with SQL Server, and rarely use Access. I have case statement in SQL server that I need to turn into a nested IIF statement in Access and I am having a hard time getting it to work. The SQL Code is:

```
(CASE 
    WHEN (RRDD = '2029' 
        THEN 'IS' 
    WHEN RRDD = '2214' OR '2219' OR '2220' OR '2221' OR '2230' OR '2265'
        THEN 'AIR' 
    WHEN RRDD = '2044' OR '2323' OR '2327' OR '2331' OR '2339' 
        THEN 'LogDist' 
    WHEN RRDD = '2037' 
        THEN 'MailInn' 
    WHEN RRDD = '2213' OR '2307' OR '2311' OR '2332' OR '2334' OR '2338' 
             OR '2705' OR '2706'
        THEN 'GFF' 
    WHEN RRDD = '2010' 
        THEN 'Corp' 
    WHEN RRDD = '2040' OR '2041' OR '2081' OR '2086' 
        THEN 'Cap' 
      ELSE NULL 
END) AS RegDIs
```

Comment: I would suggest that you create a little lookup table with the `RRDD` and the `RegDI` and then just use a join to lookup the value you want.

Comment: Your `CASE` expression is not valid, even in SQL-Server.

Comment: Create a second table with the Id's and their names an join to them. A `CASE` or `IIF` statement way of handling this problem is silly at best.

Comment: I'm dead serious fella. I would highly highly recommend creating a second table with a foreign key constraint to it instead of just writing up one of big ole `case/iif` statements every single time.

Comment: Besides, an external table will be more easily maintenable in the long run...

Answer (score 3):

This case statement is crazy -- consider moving into an external table.  It actual won't run as is -- for example, you have an extra parentheses and are using OR incorrectly.

With that said, basically you need to replace WHEN with IIF( and THEN with comma and include your next IIF as the final paramater -- this should be close:

```
(IIF(RRDD = '2029', 'IS',
    IIF(RRDD IN ('2214', '2219', '2220', '2221', '2230', '2265'), 'AIR',
    IIF(RRDD IN ('2044', '2323', '2327', '2331', '2339'), 'LogDist',
    IIF(RRDD = '2037', 'MailInn',
    IIF(RRDD IN ('2213', '2307', '2311', '2332', '2334', '2338', '2705', '2706'), 'GFF',
    IIF(RRDD = '2010', 'Corp',
    IIF(RRDD IN ('2040', '2041', '2081', '2086'), 'Cap',
    NULL)))))))) AS RegDIs
```

Comment: @user2119980 -- np, glad we could help.

Comment: I like that this *can* be done, but I would never advocate actually doing it.

Answer (score 3):

Consider `Switch` as an alternative to multiple `IIf` expressions.

```
Switch
    (
        RRDD = '2029', 'IS',
        RRDD IN ('2214','2219','2220','2221','2230','2265'), 'AIR',
        RRDD IN ('2044','2323','2327','2331','2339'), 'LogDist',
        RRDD = '2037', 'MailInn',
        RRDD IN ('2213','2307','2311','2332','2334','2338','2705','2706'), 'GFF',
        RRDD = '2010', 'Corp',
        RRDD IN ('2040','2041','2081','2086'), 'Cap'
    ) AS RegDIs
```

With `Switch`, when none of the condition match, the function returns Null.

I find `Switch` easier to understand especially when the number of `IIfs` is as large as you need for this.

Still, either the `Switch` or `IIf` approach amounts to writing data into the SQL statement.  As others mentioned, I think a lookup table would be a better approach.

```
RRDD RegDIs
2029 IS
2214 AIR
2219 AIR
2220 AIR
```

It should be easier to edit the table when needed instead of revising a complex query.

Answer (score 0):

Your original code is incorrect.  You cannot say `RRDD = '2044' OR '2323'`.  You can say:  `RRDD = '2044' OR RRDD = '2323'`.  or, you can use the `in`.

The access function `iif` only has the "then" and "else" clause.  So, you have to nest the calls.

This makes the code a bit more cumbersome.  And, keeping track of the closing parentheses can be a nightmare.  As I suggest in my comment, a small reference table would be a much more elegant solution.

Here is the code using `iif`:

```
  select iif(RRDD = '2029', 'IS',
             iif(RRDD in ('2214', '2219', '2220', '2221', '2230', '2265'), 'AIR',
                 iif(RRDD in ('2044', '2323', '2327', '2331', '2339'), 'LogDist',
                     iif(RRDD = '2037', 'MailInn',
                         iif(RRDD in ('2213', '2307', '2311', '2332', '2334', '2338', '2705', '2706'), 'GFF',
                             iif(RRDD = '2010', 'Corp',
                                 iif(RRDD in ('2040', '2041', '2081',  '2086'), 'Cap', NULL
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                     )
                 )
             ) AS RegDI)
```